# Gazebo controller spawner warning

Tags: gazebo, moveit, schunk, controller-manager, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I have a problem and I hope you can help me. :)

I have a robot: Two Schunk lwa4d arms mounted on a box.

I can load this robot in gazebo.

I can load this robot in moveit + rviz and plan path for it.

But the problem is making connection between these two. So far, I am unable of doing so. I know that in both sides, gazebo and moveit, i need to have some modifications. But my major suspicion is a warning message that I receive when launching my robot in gazebo, where it warns:

> [WARN] [WallTime: 1438070984.731293] [4.961000] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
>
> [WARN] [WallTime: 1438070984.740924] [4.954000] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.

I know it has something to do with controller_manager.
In my launch file, I have:

```
<!-- controllers -->
<rosparam file="$(find schunk_lwa4d)/config/TwoArm/TwoArm_arm_controller_v2.yaml" command="load"/>
<rosparam file="$(find schunk_lwa4d)/config/joint_state_controller.yaml" command="load"/>
<!-- start_controllers -->
<node name="joint_state_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="joint_state_controller" respawn="false" />
<node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="arm_controller" />
```

What I know for now is that each warning is related to one control spawning.
My file, joint_state_controller.yaml is very small:

```
joint_state_controller:
type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
publish_rate: 50
```

ROS is able to locate it. So the problem shouldn't be finding the file. But in spawning it using controller spawner, something is going wrong.

I tried to copy-paste the other file, TwoArm_arm_controller_v2.yaml, here too. But I couldn't format it in a good way to be easily readable. But the basic structure is something like:

```
## joint_names
joint_names: [arm1_1_joint, arm1_2_joint, arm1_3_joint, arm1_4_joint, arm1_5_joint, arm1_6_joint, arm1_7_joint, arm2_1_joint, arm2_2_joint, arm2_3_joint, arm2_4_joint, arm2_5_joint, arm2_6_joint, arm2_7_joint]
## joint trajectory controller
arm_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - arm1_1_joint
    ...
    - arm1_7_joint
    - arm2_1_joint
    ...
    - arm2_7_joint

  constraints:
    goal_time: 0.6
    stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
    arm1_1_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
    ...
    arm2_7_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
  stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
  state_publish_rate:  25
  action_monitor_rate: 10
```

What I could find by now is that there may be two reasons for this warning:

- controller manager not running.
- not launching the spawned script in the same namespace as the controller manager.

But honestly, I don't know how to move forward from this point. I know that controller_manager has been installed:

> ros@ros:~/Documents/Damon_CPP/ROS_Workspace/devel$ rospack find controller_manager

> /opt/ros/indigo/share/controller_manager

Unfortunately I don't know how to remove the warnings. I have the feeling that if Moveit can't communicate with gazebo, this warning can be a reason.
Any help is highly appreciated. :)

UPDATE:

After launching my robot in gazebo, I tried this command:

> ros@ros:~$ rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list

Nothing appears. The terminal goes frozen. I asked the same thing from my friend whose robot (2 U10 arms on a box) is loaded and controlled properly by moveit. Here is his result:

> merosy@MeRoSy-1:~$ rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list
> joint_state_controller - hardware_interface::JointStateInterface ( running )

> arm_controller - hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface ( running )

Seemingly my controller_manager is not working properly. Any suggestion?

Edit:

The first thing here to check if we include gazebo plugin in our urdf or not. I had forgotten it. So to my main robot.xacro file, I added:

```
<!-- gazebo_plugin for arm -->
<gazebo>
     <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
     </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Now the warning disappeared. But this error replaced it:

```
[ERROR] [1438148855.306557869, 1.195000000]: Could not load controller 'joint_trajectory_controller' because controller type 'position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1438148855.306675796, 1.195000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
```

I do:

```
ros@ros:~$ rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types
```

And the message was right: I didn't have joint trajectory controller in the list. I installed the stack ros_controllers. The error still exists but it has changed a bit into:

```
[ERROR] [1438241832.828501125, 1.325000000]: Could not load class joint_state_controller/JointStateController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin joint_state_controller/JointStateController. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[ERROR] [1438241832.828590337, 1.325000000]: Could not load controller 'joint_state_controller' because controller type 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1438241832.828620348, 1.325000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1438241833.829661] [2.315000] Failed to load joint_state_controller
```

This time, while the program running, in another terminal, I try again:

```
ros@ros:~$ rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types
```

And 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController' is between the results.

I again thank you for your attention and apologize if my ROS knowledge is not good enough.

Edit:

Maybe a clue:
I know that the package joint_state_controller has been installed:

```
ros@ros:~/Documents/Damon_CPP/ROS_Workspace/devel$ rospack find joint_state_controller
/opt/ros/indigo/stacks/ros_controllers/joint_state_controller
```

And I know that when loading the robot in gazebo, the controller is there [well, I don't know how to write this: the controller is ... recognized???]:

```
ros@ros:~$ rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list-types
cob_omni_drive_controller/OdometryController
cob_omni_drive_controller/WheelController
controller_manager_tests/EffortTestController
controller_manager_tests/MyDummyController
...
joint_state_controller/JointStateController
velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
...
```

But as I search the file: libjoint_state_controller.so
In opt/ros/indigo/lib

I don't find the file! Now it also gives some ideas to me why I always had problem with initial controllers of schunk (and finally I decided to remove them from sim.launch file and follow the instructions by gazebo):

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [cob_control_mode_adapter/cob_control_mode_adapter_node]: can't locate node [cob_control_mode_adapter_node] in package [cob_control_mode_adapter]
```

But anyway! Maybe this is not related! Back to the discussion, I couldn't find the .so file.
P.S.
My ros_controllers is not in opt/ros/indigo/share. I downloaded it in opt/ros/indigo/stacks. Although I don't think it makes any difference. Just said because you (Adolfo) emphasized the folder ros/indigo/**share**. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214712/gazebo-controller-spawner-warning/) by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check two things:

**Firstly**, that the `controller_manager` is running. You can check this by executing on the command line:

```
rosservice list | grep controller_manager
```

The expected output should look like:

```
/controller_manager/list_controller_types
/controller_manager/list_controllers
/controller_manager/load_controller
/controller_manager/reload_controller_libraries
/controller_manager/switch_controller
/controller_manager/unload_controller
```

If you don't get any output, then you're probably not loading the `gazebo_ros_control` plugin in your robot model:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    <robotNamespace>/MYROBOT</robotNamespace>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Notice that if you specify `<robotNamespace>` above (it's optional), the `controller_manager` ROS API will be namespaced to `/MYROBOT/controller_manager/...`

**Secondly**, check that the `controller_manager` and the `spawner` are in the same namespace. That is, if you spawn the `controller_manager` under the MYROBOT namespace, the `spawner` should be pushed to the same namespace as well. roslaunch allows spawning nodes in namespaces.

You might be interested in this [related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/198929/running-controller_manager-spawner-with-mybotrobot_description/)

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 31

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-29**:
Thank you so much Adolfo. You were right and I added the plugin. So the warning disappeared. Nevertheless, now I see another problem:
Could not load class joint_state_controller/JointStateController: Could not find library corresponding to plugin joint_state_controller/JointStateControlle

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-29**:
I know that joint_state_controller/JointStateController is between my controllers. I see it when:

```
ros@ros:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks$ rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types
```

:(

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-07-29**:
Are you positive that the library exists and is visible by your current ROS environment?. If installing from binaries, `ros-<distro>-joint-state-controller` should be installed. If building from source, `rospack find joint_state_controller` should yield a valid path. Make sure the package is built.

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-30**:
Hi again, Adolfo.

```
ros@ros:~/Documents/Damon_CPP/ROS_Workspace/devel$ rospack find joint_state_controller
/opt/ros/indigo/stacks/ros_controllers/joint_state_controller
```

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-30**:
Before installing the stack ros_controllers, I had the same error. So your guess is true that not having the controller causes this error. BUT! The difference is that when having the package, the error says: " Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and ... "

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-30**:
@Damon: edit your original question with any new information. The comments are really way too limited to add copy/pastes of console output. Just add *Edit:* and then place whatever new info you have after that.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-07-30**:
Did you mean `/opt/ros/indigo/**share**/ros_controllers/joint_state_controller`?. Could you check that `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libjoint_state_controller.so` exists?.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-07-30**:
You mention in the question update that you **downloaded** the controller into `/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`, so, you're not installing from binaries. The actual plugin (the `.so` library) needs to be **built**, it's not part of the version-controlled files in the repository. Is this what's going on?.

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-31**:
Dear Adolfo, sadly I should admit that is exactly what was going on. :(
My wrong understanding of some basics in ROS. I feel a bit embarrassed but at least I can say that I am learning as I move forward. I hope I didn't annoy you much. :(

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-07-31**:
Great!. Happy coding then. Could you please mark the question as answered?.

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-31**:
Yes. Also the problem here was solved and I finished the project successfully. :)
Thanks Adolfo for the patience. I will try to write another answer in here as soon as I finish my thesis (deadline: 15th of August).

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-20**:
Hi, I am having the same problem.

When running:

> rosservice list | grep controller_manager

I do not get any output even if the gazebo_ros_control is loaded in my robot model. Any ideas? Can you help me?

**Comment by [Alba Garcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/30828/alba-garcia/) on 2017-06-20**:
Hi, I'm getting the same error and after following all the instructions written here, I still can't fix it.
I think the problem comes from the controller_manager and spawner namespace, but I'm not sure I understand what this exactly means.
I specify it in the plugin and .launch file.Any ideas? Thx

**Comment by [dmpatod](https://answers.ros.org/users/38030/dmpatod/) on 2019-01-23**:
https://github.com/DMPatod/industrial_robot_proj
I'm having the same problem here. I've put all namespace with the same name but the warn persist

**Comment by [Fookii](https://answers.ros.org/users/53315/fookii/) on 2020-04-07**:
For anyone who is new to ros and learning with urdf-tutorial. the second point us important cause they have in tutorial empty robot namespace.
And thanks Adolfo

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control by :

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
```

---

Originally posted by [khaled0000](https://answers.ros.org/users/34532/khaled0000/) with karma: 21 on 2018-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3